# How to get error status code and get message from error response in angular subscribe()

Tags: angular, rxjs, frontend

Code will be like this!

```
thisService.createProduct(new ProductDetail(this.data)).subscribe({
  next: (response) => {
    this.isSaved = true;

    if (this.isSaved) {
      this.createdId = Number(response);
      this.metadata.uploadEvent(this.createdId);
    }
  },
  complete: () => {
    this.snackBar.open('Product has been created.', '', {
      duration: 3000
    });
    this.router.navigate(['products']);
  },
  error: (e) => {
    if(e.status === 400){
      console.log(e)
    }
   
    this.snackBar.open(e, '', {
      duration: 3000
    });
   
  }
});
```

I want to show validation message at snackbar from 400 bad request's response for checking not allowing to create with same productName

Answer (score 0):

You can use `snackBar` in the `if`

```
error: (e) => {
if(e.status === 400){
  this.snackBar.open("Your custom error message", '', {
    duration: 3000
  });
} else {
  this.snackBar.open(e, '', {
    duration: 3000
  });
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you! But I want to get error message from api which is in 400 bad request’s response.

Comment: So you want to display the api response when it errors out? Like when the api returns `{error: {code:400, message: "error message}}`?